# Which chemokines are being produced by melanocytes?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, cancer, protein-folding, melanin

I am looking into [Vitiligo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitiligo) it's an autoimmune disease that results in apoptosis of melanocytes due to [misfolded protein accumulation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5017284/).

It also [dramatically increases breast cancer rates](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6164767/#sec3dot4-ijerph-15-01847title) (600 times) within one to five years from the first symptoms of Vitiligo. One function of melanocytes is to [produce chemokines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melanocyte#Role_in_the_immune_system) however I was unable to find any info on which ones.

**Which chemokines are being produced by melanocytes?**